# Maui How to set list items in SfComboBox DataTemplate?

Tags: combobox, maui, syncfusion

I have a list at the ViewModel

```
[ObservableProperty]
private IEnumerable<Month> _months;
```

And the class Month:

```
public class Month
{
    public string Name { get; init; }
    
    public int Value { get; init; } ...
```

I can use show the list at a SfComboBox:

```
<inputs:SfComboBox DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                   ItemsSource="{Binding Months}"
                   SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedMonth}"
                   Style="{StaticResource CalendarComboBoxMonth}" />
```

(The names are "January", "February",...)

But now I like to wrap all list items with a custom:DocumentStackLayout (a custom VisualElement inherits from StackLayout). My idea is something this:

```
<inputs:SfComboBox DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                   ItemsSource="{Binding Months}"
                   SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedMonth}"
                   Style="{StaticResource CalendarComboBoxMonth}">
    <inputs:SfComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <custom:DocumentStackLayout>
                     <Label x:DataType="IEnumerable<Month>" Text="{Binding Name}" />
                </custom:DocumentStackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </inputs:SfComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</inputs:SfComboBox>
```

But that does not work.
I also tried also creating a ModelView for the month list (instead of IEnumerable), but I can't get it work.
**How can I display the month name at the Label inside the DataTemplate?**

Comment: the data type of each `Label` is just `Month`

Answer (score 0):

The BindingContext of **DocumentStackLayout** is each Month in collection. The **label** inherits the BindingContext from its parents **DocumentStackLayout**.

You may try the following:

```
<inputs:SfComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:Month">
        <ViewCell>
            <custom:DocumentStackLayout>
                <Label  Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </custom:DocumentStackLayout>
        </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
</inputs:SfComboBox.ItemTemplate>
```

By the way, compiled bindings can improve data binding performance and it is not mandatory.

For more info, you could refer to [Compiled bindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/data-binding/compiled-bindings).

Hope it helps!